# ng-lightning modal window not displaying 'x' on the close option

Tags: ng-lightning

I have a modal working in an example todos app that i'm working on, however the 'x' in the top right hand corner isn't displaying correctly.

The console is throwing an error saying it can't find localhost:3000/assets/icons{etc...} but that directory in this project exists at localhost:3000/bower_components/salesforce-lightning-design-system/assetx{etc}. See screeny..

[image: Modal not showing 'x' in top right]

Wondering how I can get that to point to the right place? It's not defined in the html markup...

Markup:

```
<div class="slds-no-flex">
    <button type="button" nglButton="neutral" (click)="open()">New Todo</button>
    <ngl-modal [header]="noHeader ? '' : 'New Todo'" [(open)]="opened" [size]="size" [directional]="directional">
          <div body>
            <!-- form goes in here for adding new todos -->
            <div class="slds-form-element">
              <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="addTodo">Enter Todo</label>
              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <input type="text" id="addTodo" class="slds-input" placeholder="Don't forget to..." autofocus=#todoText/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <template ngl-modal-footer *ngIf="!noFooter">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" (click)="addTodo($event, todoText)">Save</button>
          </template>
    </ngl-modal>
</div>
```

todo.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from '../services/todo.service';
import { Todo } from '../todo';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'todos',
    templateUrl: `./todos.component.html`,
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit { 

    todos: Todo[];  
    //properties for modals
    opened: boolean = false;
    size: string;

    noHeader: boolean = false;
    noFooter: boolean = false;
    directional: boolean = true;

    constructor(private _todoService: TodoService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.todos = [];
        this._todoService.getTodos()
            .subscribe(todos => {
                this.todos = todos;
            })
    }



    open(size?: string) {
        this.size = size;
        this.opened = !this.opened;
    }

    cancel() {
        this.opened = false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the path for your assets like this:

```
NglModule.forRoot({
  svgPath: 'bower_components/salesforce-lightning-design-system/assets/icons',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts add the below code

```
  providers: [
    { provide: NGL_ICON_CONFIG, useValue: <NglIconConfig>{ svgPath: 'myPath' } }
  ],
```